# What am I doing wrong when formatting my flash drive to NTFS?

Tags: filesystems, partition, ntfs, mkfs

Before the attempt to format a flash drive:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
...
...
Disk /dev/sdc: 7.32 GiB, 7864320000 bytes, 15360000 sectors
Disk model: DataTraveler 3.0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F89B0513-2DBE-8D40-BCDF-22BE8A5C5E45

Device     Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 15359966 15357919  7.3G Linux filesystem
```

During the attempt:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ntfs -I /dev/sdc1 
Cluster size has been automatically set to 4096 bytes.
Initializing device with zeroes: 100% - Done.
Creating NTFS volume structures.
mkntfs completed successfully. Have a nice day.
```

After the attempt:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
...
...
Disk /dev/sdc: 7.32 GiB, 7864320000 bytes, 15360000 sectors
Disk model: DataTraveler 3.0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F89B0513-2DBE-8D40-BCDF-22BE8A5C5E45

Device     Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 15359966 15357919  7.3G Linux filesystem
```

How is it possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: TL;DR: always use [`wipefs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/wipefs) when re-doing flash drives to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 22):

Here's what you're missing.

There's a partition table and there are file systems - they are related but different. You can perfectly have partitions type `Linux filesystem` (MBR notation `Linux`) formatted as NTFS and partitions type `Microsoft basic data` (MBR notation `HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`) formatted as e.g. `ext4`.

`mkfs.*` utilities simply format the storage, they never touch the partition table.

To change the partition type in the partition table you need to use any of these tools: `fdisk`, `parted`, `sfdisk`, `gdisk`, etc.

Linux GUI applications like [GParted](https://gparted.org/) or [KDE Partition Manager](https://apps.kde.org/partitionmanager/) will set the correct partition type automatically when you create a new partition in the free space of your disk.

If you come from Windows then its partition tools do that automatically. Lastly Windows normally will refuse to mount a NTFS formatted partition when its type is **not** set to `Microsoft basic data` and if you have a partition type `Microsoft basic data` but it contains any other filesystem or its contains just binary zeros Windows will offer to format it.

Comment: NTFS is a filesystem, not a partitioning standard, and there is no practical difference between ‘Linux’ and ‘Windows’ partitions other than a few bytes in the partition table. It may also be worth noting that you _can_ just use a flat disk without a partition table for a filesystem, Windows just does not like it (though most UNIX-like systems will have no issue with it at all).

Comment: In Windows, it's called "super floppy", because floppies didn't use to have partition tables. It's been a long time since I worked with Windows, but AFAIR, it worked, you just couldn't create them using Windows builtin tools. The Windows `format` tool will always create a single partition covering the entire device for any device that is not a floppy. Not sure what the newer, more sophisticated GUI applications do.

Answer (score 10):

I assume you are confused by the `Type` `Linux filesystem`. The `Type` column in `fdisk -l` doesn't show what filesystem is on the device, it shows partition type -- on GPT this is a special [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs) that helps systems recognize what is on the device, for Linux the default is *Linux filesystem data* and `mkfs.ntfs` doesn't change that. But it's not really a big problem, important is that the filesystem is NTFS (you can check with `lsblk -f /dev/sdc1`), the GUID is mostly ignored and having a "wrong" partition type shouldn't cause issues with your flash drive when using it on Windows. If you want to change it to something more appropriate for NTFS, you can use `fdisk /dev/sdc` to do that (`t` for partition type change and `11` (check list of partition types with `L` first it can be different with different versions of `fdisk`) for `Microsoft basic data`).

Comment: The number `11` is not set in stone. Actually it has changed and is likely to change again and can differ between versions etc. `L`ist; or test with 11 but be *sure to read what it say* ;) - If using script, simply use the hex-code/ID. As for `Linux filesystem` it all depends. Linux used same GUID as *Microsoft basic data* at first but this caused some issues. As for `mkfs` it is hard to say that it ***should*** change it. Just as one *can* format a *Microsoft basic* with anything one *can* also format a *Linux fs* with anything. It is a wider classification then filesystem.

Comment: Well ... that became a lengthy and messy comment, but hope it is readable c",) - Related: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parted/2011-06/msg00028.html

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer. I actually thought that some `mkfs` commands set the partition type, but a quick test with `xfs`, `ext`, `vfat` and `pvcreate` shows I was wrong. Some partitioning tools do that -- `parted` will set "correct" partition type when creating a filesystem with `mkpart`, but it makes sense for `parted` to do that, I shouldn't expect every `mkfs` tool to be able to change partition type.

Comment: @VojtechTrefny: In general `mkfs` tools won't even be *able* to change the partition type, since they operate on the partition itself and may have no way of finding out where the partition table is stored.

Comment: An `mkfs` program **shouldn't** mess with partition table entries, even if it did have access to the partition table.  That's not its job.  Its job is to create a file system on a block device or disk image file.   Changing partition table entries is the job of partitioning tools like fdisk, gdisk, parted, etc.